# I need the cursor to come down

Tags: c, error-handling

The program is just a base 10 to base 2 converter it works fine. I just want the cursor at the new line.
I have put "\n" everywhere I can logically put it but it just does not bring the cursor to the new line. The program is doing what I need it to do.

EX
"Enter a decimal number from 0 to 18,446, 744,073,709,551,615: 156"
The binary value for 156 is:10011100{{CURSOR}}

(I want the {{CURSOR}} here)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   long int dec, num;
   int store[100], i=1,j;

   printf("Enter a decimal number from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615: ");

   scanf("%ld",&dec);

   num = dec;

   while(num!=0)
   {
      store[i++]=num%2;
      num=num/2;
   }

   printf("The binary value for %d is: ",dec);

   for(j=i-1;j>0;j--)
   {
     printf("%d",store[j]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In case you are wondering, the downvotes are probably coming from the emotionally overwrought and non-descriptive title. Your question is legit in and of itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all is said and done, you need to print a newline after the number is done using `printf("\n")`. The rest, like you said, does what it should:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   long int dec, num;
   int store[100], i=1,j;

   printf("Enter a decimal number from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615: ");

   scanf("%ld",&dec);

   num = dec;

   while(num!=0)
   {
      store[i++]=num%2;
      num=num/2;
   }

   printf("The binary value for %d is: ",dec);

   for(j=i-1;j>0;j--)
   {
     printf("%d",store[j]);
   }

   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```